# Append data from Reference table to another table in Doctrine and Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, database, doctrine-orm, codeigniter-2

I have a Departments reference table like:

```
Id Name
1. Dept1
2. Dept2
3. Dept3
```

I have a Users table like:

```
Id Name  
1. User1 
2. User2
```

On adding a user I want to be able to assign them a department. However I dont want to 
store the department name in the user table, hence the reference table. So I was thinking I should have a Dept_id field in the User table so as to make the reference to the Department table.

Problem is I need to output the `User id, User Name and Department name` after adding the user. Challenge is I am doing this by:

```
$array['users'] = Users::getUsersAll();
$this -> table -> set_heading(array('id', 'Name');
```

In the model the `getUsersAll()` method contains:

> $query = Doctrine_Query::create() -> select("id,Name") ->
>   from("users")

In the view, I generate the table by:

```
echo $this -> table -> generate($users);
```

How then would I be able to query and output the name of the department and append it to the table containing the the rest of the user data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your description,  user class will be something similar.

```
class User
    {

    /** Other members ...... **/

    /** @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Department") */
    public $department;

    }
```

You can access the Department name from User object by `$user->department->name`

Answer (score 0):

Create a view by joining the User and Department table. Then use the view for fetching the records. That will be the best performing approach.